# use multiple conditions in if and if not statement (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read a text from a text file, read lines, and delete short lines and lines that contain specific string (for example, 'bad' and 'naughty').
I can't seem to make this happen with this code:

```
bad_words = ['bad', 'naughty']

with open('oldfile.txt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words) or len(line) > 20:
            newfile.write(line)
```

I suspect that the problem has to do with using if and if not. Any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Do you really have a `::` there? That's going to be a `SyntaxError`...

Comment: Fixing your syntax error(s) would be a good start.

Comment: thanks. fixed the syntax error. now I would love to know hoe to make the code do what I want (:

Comment: You also say bad "words" but your current code is looking for substrings... but the main thing is... you don't want `or`/the `not` here... have a think about your boolean logic :)

Comment: So you want to write lines that have no bad words AND are not too short; correct?

Comment: @ScottHunter think you've given away what I was trying to hint there :p (OP: once that clicks - I'd also move the length check first as that's a much faster check to make before looking at the content of the string - good luck!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a working version of your code. Your problem was the `or`. You should use the `and` operator because you want to write the line to the new file only if the lenght of the line is grater than 20 **AND** it doesn't contains bad word.

**Code:**

```
bad_words = ["bad", "naughty"]

with open("oldfile.txt") as oldfile, open("newfile.txt", "w") as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if len(line) > 20 and not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

**Test:**

*oldfile.txt content:*

```
Short line
This is a very long lineeeeeeeeeeeeeee
This is a bad line
This is a naughty line
This is also a very good line
```

*Run the script:*

```
>>> python3 test.py
```

*newfile.txt content:*

```
This is a very long lineeeeeeeeeeeeeee
This is also a very good line
```